# Why does dataproc not create two executors per worker when spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead is configured?

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

Dataproc is supposed to fit in two Executors per worker (or yarn NodeManager) with each one getting half the cores and half the memory. 
And it does work that way.

However, if we override a setting, say spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=4096

then it only creates one Executor per worker. Half the cores and memory of the clusters are not utilized. And no matter how we play around with spark.executor.memory or spark.executor.cores, it still doesn't spin up enough executors to utilize all cluster resources.

How to make dataproc still create 2 executors per worker? The yarn overhead is deducted out of the executor memory, so it should still be able to fit in 2 executors, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When executing in YARN, Spark will request containers with memory sized as spark.executor.memory + spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead. If you're adding to memoryOverhead, you will want to subtract an equal amount from spark.executor.memory to preserve the same container packing characteristics.

Comment: Yes. My mistake was, on a n8 node with 30G memory and 3G configured overhead, I was trying to have 11G as executor memory: and I still got only one executor. Reducing that to 10G gave me two exectors per worker

Comment: Thanks for giving specifics. That helps clarify.